# How to install a library from github?

Tags: python

Trying to install this library.

https://github.com/pib/PyBrowser

with the command

```
pip install git+https://github.com/pib/PyBrowser.git
```

and run into this error

```
setup.py
```

So I just cloned the repo in my sites-packages folder, but it still isnt seeing it as installed in python...

Thanks!

Comment: That's not an error message, that's a file name. Please [edit] your question to include the precise error message.

Answer (score 3):

That is not a library, it's an application.  It's not designed to be installed as a package that can be used in other applications.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry about that. My friend installed a library in his program that we share and imported it like this

Comment: from pybrowser.browser import Session, ProxySession

Comment: Thought it was this library. Looked exactly the same